# how do I recreate the sencha style gesture scroll for lists and content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, extjs, sencha-touch

So... I am working on an interaction design project and I want to create a sencha-style gesture scroll for content areas.  The way I've done it so far, is to attach touchmove/start/end events to the content area, and it translateY's the contents. It works in on desktop with mousemove/up/down events, but it jumps around like crazy with touch. I'm not sure whats wrong.. here is a link to a prototype.

**requires webkit.

http://apps.omorphos.com/gesture-scroll

I think it is an issue with the event response, but I tried and haven't been able to nail it down. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out.

What I was doing was attaching the touch event to the list tag itself.. and, that works fine on desktop with mouse events; however, with touch,  the target changes and touchend doesn't fire properly.

So, what I did, and what I believe sencha does, ... and I had originally implemented but went in a different direction... is have an absolutely positioned element with a transparent background color floating above the element that will be manipulated. All of the touch events will be captured by that DIV and then the elements below can be manipulated without losing the event data.

In the new version I used HammerJs ... more info: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ 
but i'm pretty sure you could just use standard events; but the good thing about hammer js, is that it will translate touch events to mouse events for testing in the browser, this also means making the coordinates for touch the same as mouse, so you can access mouse event coords via

```
e.gesture.touches[0].pageX
e.gesture.touches[0].pageY
```

which let's you write less code.

Part 2:

Additionally... part of the issue is... how do you click on the content/components(e.g. links) below the screen.

How you do this... is you take the coords from the event handler and pass them through this native Javascript function...

```
var a = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

this will return the dom element. and all you have to do is trigger the click/tap event.

Which would be great, except it will pick the element with the highest z-index.. so that is your screen obj(the one that is capturing all of the touch events). So, what you need to do, is hide the screen after a tap is registered, and then execute this function 200ms later, and then bring back the screen to capture whatever events.

You can do this with this function...

```
$(theScreen).on('tap', function(e){
    screen.hide();
    var hit = document.elementFromPoint(e.gesture.touches[0].pageX, e.gesture.touches[0].pageY);
    $(hit)[0].tagName !=="A" || $(hit).trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function(){screen.show()},300);
});
```

And, that is how I solved it!
My code is not super annotated, but you can find it at the link below:

Updated example: 
http://apps.omorphos.com/gesture-scroll/v2/

Comment: The Updated example: http://apps.omorphos.com/gesture-scroll/v2/ is not working with keyboard hand gesture(tested in safari and chrome)

Comment: I figured this out a long time ago but my version isn't nearly as put together as IScroll, so I've been using IScroll in all of my projects since.